# Cascade Delete Children not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

I have two tables one of which is for the polymorphic relationship of different corporations and I've added foreign key references to ids to ensure that if I delete a parent all children will be deleted. With this table setup below if I delete a parent corporation the child corporation persists which is not what I expected. If I delete a corporation_relationship via the parent_id the parent and its children cascade delete and if I a delete the relationship via the child_id the parent and siblings are unaffected. My questions are what am I doing wrong and how can I ensure that by deleting a parent the children are also deleted without adding any new columns?

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TYPE "corporation_relationship_type" AS ENUM (
  'campus',
  'network'
);

CREATE TABLE "corporations" (
  "id" uuid PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "corporation_relationships" (
  "parent_id" uuid NOT NULL,
  "child_id" uuid NOT NULL,
  "type" corporation_relationship_type NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("parent_id", "child_id")
);

ALTER TABLE "corporation_relationships" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("parent_id") REFERENCES "corporations" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE "corporation_relationships" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("child_id") REFERENCES "corporations" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Example queries:

If I add 2 corporations and then add a relationship to the two like so:

```
insert into corporations (id, name) values ('f9f8f7f6-f5f4f3f2-f1f0f0f0-f0f0f0f0', 'Father');


insert into corporations (id, name) values ('f9f8f7f6-f5f4f3f2-f1f0f0f0-f0f0f0f1', 'Son');

insert into corporation_relationships (parent_id, child_id) values ('f9f8f7f6-f5f4f3f2-f1f0f0f0-f0f0f0f0', 'f9f8f7f6-f5f4f3f2-f1f0f0f0-f0f0f0f1');
```

My output for `select * from corporations;` will be:

```
                  id                  |        name
--------------------------------------+--------------------
 f9f8f7f6-f5f4-f3f2-f1f0-f0f0f0f0f0f0 | Father
 f9f8f7f6-f5f4-f3f2-f1f0-f0f0f0f0f0f1 | Son
(2 rows)
```

My output for `select * from corporation_relationships;` is:

```
              parent_id               |               child_id               |  type
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------
 f9f8f7f6-f5f4-f3f2-f1f0-f0f0f0f0f0f0 | f9f8f7f6-f5f4-f3f2-f1f0-f0f0f0f0f0f1 | campus
```

Now if I delete the 'father' by executing `delete FROM corporations WHERE id = 'f9f8f7f6-f5f4-f3f2-f1f0-f0f0f0f0f0f0';` I would expect my output of `select * from corporations;` to be nothing but instead it is the following:

```
                  id                  |        name
--------------------------------------+--------------------
 f9f8f7f6-f5f4-f3f2-f1f0-f0f0f0f0f0f1 | Son
(1 row)
```

Also, it is noteworthy that the corporation_relationships table is empty after this delete as well but I would want the cascade to keep going past that table and delete the child entity as well.

Comment: The only way this is going to work is by deleting the appropriate `corporations.id`. The `ON DELETE CASCADE` goes from `corporations` to `corporation_relationships`. Since  a parent can have many children I would expect that deleting one child would not delete the parent.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, maybe I didn't explain myself well. What you're describing as the "only way this is going to work" is what I'm trying to do and what is not working as expected. When I delete a coproration that has children they are not being deleted as well.

Comment: That is not what you said: "If I delete a corporation_relationship via the parent_id the parent and its children cascade delete". You will need to provide some example data as well as the actual queries you are using in order to get a complete answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I've added some sample queries hopefully to better explain my issue.

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` only goes one way from parent table to child table. You want it to reverse direction and delete a parent record when the child record is deleted and that will not happen. I would be dangerous if it did, as deleting the parent would create a cascade on all those records that referred to it. I could also see this creating a recursion situation. Your best bet is to set up a parent table with the 'father' records and a child table with the `son` records. Then a delete of a father would delete all the sons.

Answer (score 0):

Your second foreign key constraint in the `corporation_relationships` table, that references to the `corporations` table has nothing with with your expectations of cascade deletions of children rows in `corporations`. To clearify, this foreign key do cascade deletions **when you delete a referenced row in the `corporations` table**. But you need the opposite.

To make it work as you expect *in your design*, you should have **a column in `corporations` that references a primary key in `corporation_relationships`**.

So you need to

1. **create a primary key column**, e.g. *id*, **in `corporation_relationships`** (not those you already have, it's not a pk, it's a unique constraint).
2. **create a column in `corporations`** and **add a foreign key** constraint on it that **references** a created **`corporation_relationships` pk**.
3. **Remove a `child_id` column from `corporation_relationships`**, it's incorrect and useless at this point.
4. When you create a relation you should set it's *id* to the *fk column* of corresponding *child row* in `corporations`.
   Now, if you delete a *parent corporation*, it would delete all *relationships*, those will delete corresponding *children of corporation* and so on recursively.

Meanwhile, in my opinion, your design is not correct.

To define a tree-like relations you do not need the transit table, i.e
`corporation_relationships`. You can define it in a single `corporations` table. For that you need just a one column *parent_id*, those would be a foreign key with cascade delete rule, that references a *pk* in this table. Top-parent *corporations* would have a **null** in *parent_id*, all children - parent's *id* value.

Also, *type* column in `corporation_relationships` is not an attribute of relation itself, it's an attribute of child.

Comment: I like your idea of adding an id column to the `corporation_relationships` table as a primary key and adding a reference to it in the `organizations` table but I disagree that `child_id` is not needed or useless or incorrect. Also type is an attribute of the relationship itself not the child and I am not able to add a column to the corporations table so that kind of simplistic approach will not benefit me here.

Comment: @Josh Wren, what is it's purpose in this case?

Comment: Delete a relation , if child is deleted? But it should be done in opposite way. Relation should be deleted and it should delete a child.

Comment: to find a parent given a child_id for one

Comment: You have all you need to find a parent of a child  without storing redundant data. Your child references a relation, those references a parent

Comment: I feel like you're zeroing in on irrelevant information but I see what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres doesn't mantain referential integrity with optional polymorphic relationships so I created a trigger to do this for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION cascade_delete_children() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        -- Check if the corporation is a parent
        IF OLD.id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM corporation_relationships) THEN
            -- Delete all of the corporation's children
            DELETE FROM corporations WHERE id IN (SELECT child_id FROM corporation_relationships WHERE parent_id = OLD.id);
        END IF;
        RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE trigger cascade_delete_children BEFORE DELETE ON corporations
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE cascade_delete_children();
```

Comment: Meanwhile you can execute`delete` query without checking of existence of `id` value in `parent_id` column. You just do not need one more query to execute